# Loading graphics in Grafana

Tags: raspberry-pi, grafana

I am using a Raspberry Pi to show some graphs in Grafana. I only use the raspberry to put the URL in the Chromium. I have shown these graphs for 4 months. But now some of these graphics do not load (line charts).

[image]

But if I enter the same URL with my computer the graph is shown.
[image]

What could be going on? Could it be a memory problem?

Comment: Grafana needs a lot of browser-side performance, yes. If it’s causing this particular problem, who knows. Are you sure the data is properly aggregated by time intervals?

Comment: Yes, I am sure.  I've been receiving data in Grafana for almost 4 months. But now I can't see any data in Grafana even in those months. And if I enter in the same dashboard using a different system (my laptop for example) I can see the data properly.

Comment: Did you perhaps change/upgrade software on the Pi?

Comment: No, I haven't changed/updated anything. I just tried to display the dashboard on two TVs. In one of them I can see the graphics, but not in the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end, it was that it was not well set the time in the raspberry and although I entered the URL I had been set to visualize last hour and I was catching the wrong time of day.